# Can I create a macro which is only testing a condition?

Tags: oracle

the following query doesn't work if doesn't comment WHERE fc().

```
WITH
 FUNCTION ft 
        RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO(table)
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN q'{
      ta
  }';
    END;

 FUNCTION fc 
        RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO(scalar)
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN q'{
      1=1
  }';
    END;
      ta(v) as (select 1 from dual)  
SELECT *
  FROM ft()
 WHERE fc()
```

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Have I done some syntax error or isn't it possible to make macro returning a condition?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c10a779f7a2847a4597ffe1a25418108)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Macro is not a way to inject arbitrary part of the code into the SQL statement, but an expression or a table. It is described [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-3C11D3A9-8B14-4DCC-B212-B7FE57EE81E8):

> SQL macros can either be **scalar expressions**, typically used in SELECT lists, WHERE, GROUPBY and HAVING clauses, to encapsulate calculations and business logic or can be **table expressions**, typically used in a FROM clause.

So macros may be used where expressions may be used, and expressions require some operator in the `where` clause.